# Infinite Set Bijection

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

> 1.) Let $S$ be an infinite set. Show that $S$ has a subset $T$ which is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$.

Also,

> 2.) Let $S$ be an infinite set. Using 1, Show that there exists a proper subset $T$ of $S$ such that $T$ is in bijection with $S$.

It appears that I have to consider 2 cases: S is countable and S is uncountable, but also apparently the Axiom of Choice is also used for this proof?

Any help, tips, or a fully worked out solution would be appreciated!

Comment: Try to give a map. Hint if you take finitely many elements out it's still infinite

Comment: What is your definition of “infinite”?

Answer (score 0):

2) follows from 1): Let $S$ be infinite and, according to 1), let $T_1$ be a subset of $S$ and $f\colon T_1\to \Bbb N$ a bijection. Then let $T_2=S\setminus \{f^{-1}(0)\}$ and define the bijection $g\colon S\to T_2$ by
$$ g(x)=\begin{cases}x&x\notin T_1\\f^{-1}(f(x)+1)&x\in T_1\end{cases}$$

---

For 1), define injective $f\colon \Bbb N\to S$ recursively: If $f(k)$ is already defined for all $k<n$, then $A_n:=\{\,f(k)\mid k<n\,\}$ cannot be all of $S$ (or else $f$ as defined so far is a bijection that shows that $S$ is finite). Hence we can set $f(n)=s$ for some $s\in S\setminus A_n$. (And, yes, this latter step uses some mild form of Choice)

Comment: could you elaborate further on 1?